# Groovy script to run grails command

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I wanted to create a groovy script to run grails clean, grails compile and grails run-app, However, I noticed that I cannot run any of the grails commands. In fact then I tried to run the following script on the Groovy Console:

```
 def envs = System.getenv().collect{"$it.key=$it.value"}
    //println envs
    println "java -version".execute(envs, new File("c:\\")).err.text
    println "grails -version".execute(envs, new File("c:\\")).text
```

This itself gives me the following output:

```
groovy> def envs = System.getenv().collect{"$it.key=$it.value"} 
groovy> //println envs 
groovy> println "java -version".execute(envs, new File("c:\\")).err.text 
groovy> println "grails -version".execute(envs, new File("c:\\")).text 


    java version "1.7.0_06"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_06-b24)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

    Exception thrown

    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grails" (in directory "c:\"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

        at ConsoleScript26.run(ConsoleScript26:4)

    Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

        ... 1 more
```

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, the `grails` command is a `.bat` file, and you can't run `.bat` files directly using `Runtime.exec` or `ProcessBuilder` (which is what `"...".execute` ultimately delegates to).

Use `cmd /c`:

```
println ["cmd", "/c", "grails -version"].execute(envs, new File("c:\\")).text
```

or possibly

```
println ["cmd", "/c", "grails", "-version"].execute(envs, new File("c:\\")).text
```

I'm not sure whether the "grails -version" needs to be one argument or two (it may be that both ways work, I'm not currently in a position to test this).

Answer (score 0):

If `java - version` runs and `grails -version` not, it means that you don't updated your `PATH` environment variable. Append the location to the `bin` folder to the variable.

Since Grails is just a zip, you need to do it manually.